# How to rotate image with fix point along with touch in android

Tags: android

I've been looking for over a day for a solution to this problem but nothing helped, even the answers here didn't helped me.
my problem is my image is rotating but bitmap size is not varying while rotating.

here is my code

```
package dharam.rotate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Rotate extends Activity {
    View baseView ;
    ImageView turntable;
    TextView bottomText;
    GestureDetector   gestureDetector;
    private float x , y;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    baseView = (View) findViewById(R.id.baseView);
    turntable = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.turntable);

    turntable.setOnTouchListener(onTableTouched);
    baseView.setOnTouchListener(onTableTouched);
}

public android.view.View.OnTouchListener onTableTouched = new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt) {
        double r = Math.atan2(evt.getX() - turntable.getWidth() / 2,
                (turntable.getHeight() / 2) - evt.getY());
        int rotation = (int) Math.toDegrees(r);
        Log.i("R is ", ""+r);
        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        }

        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            x= evt.getX();
            y= evt.getY();
            updateRotation(rotation);
        }

        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //
        }
        return true;
    }
};
private void updateRotation(double rot) {
    float newRot = new Float(rot);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.orsl_circle_transparent);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
//        matrix.setTranslate(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2, getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
        matrix.postRotate(newRot,bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2);
//      matrix.setSinCos(newRot, newRot/2, 100, 100);
//      matrix.postRotate(newRot);
        Log.i("THE ROATTION ", "  "+    newRot);

    if(y>250)
    {
        Bitmap redrawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap
                .getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        turntable.setImageBitmap(redrawnBitmap);
    }else
    {
        Bitmap  redrawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap
                .getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
         turntable.setImageBitmap(redrawnBitmap);
         Log.i("GUITAR _IMAGE", "");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: @dhams What have you tried? Can your code at least "see" (i.e. process) touch events?

Comment: Also, what touch event do you want to respond to? I assume dragging/swiping but more details would be helpful.

Comment: hey i have update ma code ,,,plz check it..

Comment: Hi @Dhams.. did you get the solution for it?

Comment: Its 'My' , not 'Ma'. please avoid using chat lingo here

Comment: @Sheikh aman : thats fine ...i'll remember that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want to rotate an image at the point where a user touches the screen? If so, extend the SimpleOnGestureListener like this example:

```
public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener
{       

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event)
    {
        int X = (int)event.getX();          
        int Y = (int)event.getY();

        ...Rotate the image
    }
}
```

Once you've got the screen coordinates of the touch event, you could apply a Rotation Animation about the point - see here for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code just by not taking the baseview and it works fine. Here is my code and it works fine in my emulator.

```
package com.android.practice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class JobSearch extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

private ImageView dialer;
private float y=0;
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    double r=Math.atan2(event.getX()-dialer.getWidth()/2, dialer.getHeight()/2-event.getY());
    int rotation=(int)Math.toDegrees(r);
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //x=event.getX();
            y=event.getY();
            updateRotation(rotation);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
    }//switch       

    return true;

}//onTouch
private void updateRotation(double rot){
    float newRot=new Float(rot);
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.round_button_big);
    Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(newRot,bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2);
    if(y>250){
        Bitmap reDrawnBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
        dialer.setImageBitmap(reDrawnBitmap);
    }
    else{
        Bitmap reDrawnBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
        dialer.setImageBitmap(reDrawnBitmap);
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dialer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.big_button);
    dialer.setOnTouchListener(this);
}//onCreate
}
```